# How do I keep a variable value after UI state change?

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive

So basically, I have an ImagePicker widget that empties every time my view changes in a browser(flutter web):

[image: Full screen browser]

But once I change the size of the browser window, the image dissappears:

[image]

So I was wondering if there's a way to keep value of the variable that contains the string image.

This is the function that gets the image:

```
    static Future<Uint8List?> webPickImage() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    var file = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (file != null) {
      return await file.readAsBytes();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

As you can see, this returns an `Uint8List` which then is emited in a BLoC/cubit state management class variable

```
    void userWebImageChanged() async {
    final newWebImage = await CommonFunction.webPickImage();
    emit(
      state.copyWith(
        webUserImage: newWebImage,
      ),
    );
  }
```

**State management class:**
So it appears that `webUserImage` loses it's value when the browser window changes size:

```
    part of 'sign_up_cubit.dart';

class SignUpState extends Equatable {
  const SignUpState(
  {
    this.webUserImage
  });

  final Uint8List? webUserImage;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        webUserImage
      ];

  SignUpState copyWith(
      {
      Uint8List? webUserImage
      }) {
    return SignUpState(
        webUserImage: webUserImage ?? this.webUserImage);
  }
}
```

**Widget(read comments):**

```
        class SignUpForm extends StatelessWidget {
      const SignUpForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => SignUpCubit(),
            child: BlocConsumer<SignUpCubit, SignUpState>(
              builder: (context, state) => ResponsiveRowColumn(
                  rowMainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  rowPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  columnPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  layout: ResponsiveWrapper.of(context).isSmallerThan(DESKTOP)
                      ? ResponsiveRowColumnType.COLUMN
                      : ResponsiveRowColumnType.ROW,
                  children: [
                    ResponsiveRowColumnItem(
                        rowFlex: 1,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          width: 350,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Wrap(
                                runSpacing: 10,
                                alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  ResponsiveVisibility(
                                    hiddenWhen: const [
                                      Condition.smallerThan(name: TABLET)
                                    ],
    //BLoC
                                    child: BlocBuilder<SignUpCubit, SignUpState>(
                                      buildWhen: (previous, current) =>
                                          previous.webUserImage !=
                                          current.webUserImage,
                                      builder: (cubitContext, state) {
                                        return GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () async {
                                            cubitContext
                                                .read<SignUpCubit>()
                                                .userWebImageChanged();
                                          },
                                          child: Container(
                                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                            width: 135,
                                            height: 135,
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    const BorderRadius.all(
                                                        Radius.circular(10)),
                                                border: Border.all(
                                                  color: Theme.of(context)
                                                      .primaryColorDark,
                                                  width: 1,
                                                ),
                                                color: Colors.white),
                                            child: state.webUserImage == null
                                                ? Center(
                                                    child: Icon(
                                                      Icons.add,
                                                      color: Theme.of(context)
                                                          .primaryColorDark,
                                                      size: 50,
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                : ClipRRect(
                                                    child: Image.memory(
    // This is the state variable that sets and holds the image:                                                    
                                             state.webUserImage!),
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        const BorderRadius.all(
                                                            Radius.circular(11)),
                                                  ),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),
    //...
```

Comment: Can you include your widget , seems like your image variable  inside the build method

Comment: Your code isn't quite clear and complete, but you probably have a tight coupling between the UI update logic and the data fetch. You should use one of the State Management approach suggested by Flutter documentation, like BLoC for instance, to wrap and isolate the data into a Controller/Stream. With a StreamBuilder widget it would only update if an new event has been sank into the stream.

Comment: I updated my question with further details...
@YeasinSheikh My variable is in the state management class

Comment: @DouglasFerreira I'm already using BLoC/Cubit state management (or correct me if I'm wrong plz)

Comment: You should keep image data in `SignUpCubit`. The `SignUpCubit` should keep it's state during widget build.

Comment: @JunYaoYuan Can you provide an example of how would you do it?